# SIM popup messages keep the screen on indefinitely (Samsung A30s)

Tags: samsung, notifications, android-10, samsung-one-ui, sim-toolkit

**A little background:** In my country, carriers keep sending those annoying pop-up messages (I think they're called class-0 messages?). This has been the case for a couple of years and they won't stop no matter what you do. Anyway, it wasn't a big deal with my previous phones; I just learned to ignore them.

However, with my A30s (which I've had for a few months), I'm facing a critical issue where the screen will turn on for the message and never turn off unless I close the pop-up or manually turn it off by pressing the power button. There are basically two types of those messages:

1. Ones that show up after a call is ended (very annoying but avoidable if I remember to close the message after ending the call):

   [image: Messages that show up after call]
2. Ones that show up randomly (sometimes at night while I'm asleep. Screen stays on overnight and **drains the battery**):

   [image: Message that pop up randomly]

I couldn't even tell which app is responsible for displaying those messages. Here's what I've tried:

- Checked the permissions for the Messages app and the Phone app to see if there's something that controls this.
- Disabled the "draw over other apps" permission for the Messages app.
- Installed Google's Messages app and set it as default (since I can't uninstall or disable the main one).
- I also checked the permissions for the "SIM toolkit" app but there were none. I tried disabling the notifications but the option was grayed out.

None of the above helped.

**Does anyone know how to get rid of these messages?**

Note: I want to avoid rooting the device or installing a custom rom.

I tried reporting this to Samsung but they weren't very helpful.

Comment: One simple workaround would be to activate Airplane mode at night. It has the advantage of less battery consumption and no one can disturb you when you are sleeping.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the suggestion! However, it doesn't only happen at night. It happens during the day as well and I might not notice it for hours if I'm not using the phone. Also, I don't prefer turning off the phone at night, in case of an urgent/emergency call or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download Automate app and make a flow like this..

[image: IMG:]

Allow the permissions And then configure it like this. Notice the option "When UI element appear".

[image: IMG:]

Then click on record. Now, make a call and end/hang up it so that you get the dialog-box. Click on Cancel in the dialog box, see the details and try to understand if the interaction has been recorded. If yes, then click OK.

What it does is that it automatically clicks the Cancel button as soon as it appears on the screen.

I haven't received any dialog box for years so I don't know if that's gonna work. If it doesn't, just see the options from `+` icon and try to do something else. There are like a hundred options. If that too doesn't work then let me know.

Comment: Okay, this did help (+1). It does close the dialog but unfortunately it closes every dialog with input field and a cancel button (for example the ones you interact with using codes like `*xxx#`. I tried to create a condition based on the dialog text but the interactions that I recorded doesn't have anything that includes the text of that UI element. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Change the action in the interact block(it probably will be select or click) change it to inspect then add another block of delay 10 seconds and then copy the first block and paste it and connect it after the delay. So that the order is (Interact1 > Delay > Interact2). In interact2 change the action to click or select the cancel button. What is does is checks if the cancel button is present. if yes then it waits for user to cancel it (in 10sec) if user doesn't cancel it then it will automatically do so.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I did :-D (I used 30 sec. delay though to allow for typing and sending if required). I was just hoping there would be a better way that depends on the text and doesn't rely on a delay. I think that's good enough though. Will accept your answer soon because it did help me. Thanks again :)

Comment: And if in cast you want to cancel the specific money remaining and all dialog box then try this experiment. Start record interaction and when the dialog box pops up click on the text it will get recorded. In automate select the interaction and in "ui element text" remove the variable things (like the amount which changes everytime). This does rely on text as you wanted and is the most efficient way i guess. Thanks to you! I too didn't know there's so much in automate yet. I just used it for simple automations.

Comment: I just want to know did the automate app auto close the random promotions pop up you were also getting from your carrier, or just the after call pop ups? Thanks,

Comment: @Suliemans You can set that if the pop-up contains some specific text then cancel it else not.